# Create an increasing vector, but consider number of occurences of equal elements in another vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
A = 

5873 4

5873 7

5873 1

2819 8

2819 1

9771 4

9771 2

9771 5

9771 6

5548 7
```

What I would like to do is to create a new column that puts an order to the times that the unique identifier (i.e. the entry in the first column) appears in the array. Something like this:

```
B = 

5873 4 1

5873 7 1

5873 1 1

2819 8 2

2819 1 2

9771 4 3

9771 2 3

9771 5 3

9771 6 3

5548 7 4
```

Does anyone know of an elegant way to do this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer by @thewaywewalk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25092596/2586922) is the way to go. However, if your Matlab version is not recent enough, the [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function doesn't have the `'stable'` option. In that case you can do it very easily with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
[~, e] = max(bsxfun(@eq, A(:,1), A(:,1).'));
k = cumsum([1 diff(e)] > 0);
B = [A k.'];
```

*This works as follows*:

For each entry in the first column of `A`, vector `e`  gives the index of the first occurrence of that value (the second output of [`max`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/max.html) gives the *first* location of the maximizer). In your example, `e` is: 1,1,1,4,4,6,... Then, vector `k` transforms that sequence into consecutive numbers: 1,1,1,2,2,3,... From that the result is built.

Comment: +1, Thanks for pointing out the version dependency of `unique`. I actually had a different approach in my first revision, which is now valid again. Quite similar to yours, but a little shorter, but probably also more memory consuming. Have a look at my edit, if interested.

Comment: This one works really well, too! Thanks so much for responding!!

Comment: Thanks! Note that if you have a recent enough Matlab version, the `unique` approach with the `'stable'` option may be neater. Have you tried which is faster?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Matlab has a built-in function to do this, but you can implement it yourself pretty easily:

```
B = [A zeros(size(A,1),1)];  %Preallocate memory
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    B(i,3) = sum(A(:,1) == A(i,1)); %Count how many occurrences 
end
```

This isn't super efficient, as it performs a bunch of redundant calculations, but it'll get the job done. Also, be careful with this if you start working with non-integer data: as of 2013b, Matlab says the statement 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3 is false (due to floating point quirkiness) so the above code could give some mysterious results.

Answer (score 1):

Use the third output of [**`unique`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) in `'stable'`-mode:

```
[~,~,Y] =  unique( A(:,1), 'stable') 
B = [A Y]
```

gives:

```
B =

        5873           4           1
        5873           7           1
        5873           1           1
        2819           8           2
        2819           1           2
        9771           4           3
        9771           2           3
        9771           5           3
        9771           6           3
        5548           7           4
```

As pointed out by Luis Mendo, the `'stable'` option of unique was just introduced with **Matlab 2013a**. For older versions I suggest my first idea using [**`accumarray`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
%// count number of occurences and create vector of zeroes with the same length
%// but first element set to 1
X = accumarray(A(:,1),A(:,1),[],@(x) {[1 zeros(1, numel(x)-1) ]} )

%// reordering and cumulative sum gives the desired output vector
B = [A cumsum([X{:}])']
```

Comment: Nice use of `accumarray` (although using cells it may not be very fast). You already had my +1 :-)

Comment: Thanks! It worked great and was super fast! Really appreciate the help.